# Entity Framework causes data loss in MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, mysql-connector

I wrote an application in C# which uses MySQL as a database (InnoDB) and application handles data through entity framework (MySQL connector). There are several problems which I faced during a year.

If there is a power outage, then sometimes data in MySQL database is lost and you can't recover. Because problem is related to log sequence which does not match. I read about that error, and saw that EF does not write data to MySQL and even does not give any warning or exception. 
1) Data loss was in last records during a day, or sometimes even during a week (loss of data of several days).

2) Data loss was in the middle of records, for example: there is a data from 1st till 15th, then no data for 16th, 17th, and again data for 18th of month.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this a `MySQL` issue, rather than a programming problem?

Comment: I concur with @GertArnold that this cannot be a programming issue. It seems more like an environmental issue making the database go away/unavailable at certain periods. You might also want to see if there isn't a catch all exception handler that is swallowing potential exceptions when such outages occur.

Comment: Hi, the application does not catch any db issues like mentioned. I also think that it looks MySQL problem, but still couldn't find any fixes or solutions even forum discussions about that. The versions of xampp and connector are as follows:

MySQL Connector v6.6.7
XAMPP 5.6.30

XAMPP uses MariaDB which is the version of MySQL.